# Suma de td con class

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hola como puedo sumar los valores de la columna con la clase llamada sumar `<td class="sumar">VALOR ENTERO</td>` teniendo en cuenta que es un ciclo `foreach` y se imprimirán varios valores con la misma clase.

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CANT.</th>
                    <th>ARTICULO</th>
                    <th>V.UNITARIO</th>
                    <th>V.TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($prod_alquilado as $producto): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $producto['cantidad'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto['articulo'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "$".$producto['valor_unitario'] ?></td>
                        <td class="sumar"><?php echo ($producto['valor_unitario']*$producto['cantidad']) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: right;" colspan="3">TOTAL:</th>
                    <td>$</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Quedo atento.

Comment: Una duda: vas a añadir filas dinámicamente (con javascript)? Si no es así, creo que sería más fácil hacer la suma en backend con php y simplemente añadir la cantidad al generar el HTML

Answer (score 0):

Haz un fichero javascript que recoja los valores que contenga la columna `sumar`

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("sumar");
```

Para esto necesitas que sumar sea un array: `class="sumar[]"`

Y no simplemente recorre el array y vas sumando los valores que contiene.

```
for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    //Sumar
}
```

Comment: Interesante tu respuesta, sin embargo no entiendo como imprimir el resultado.